# Using JS how can I output the data on a title attribute?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have code that looks like this:

```
<i class="my-class" title="AB">
    ::before
</i>
```

I would like to output the title's value, AB

The output could look something like this:

```
<span class="my-class">AB</span>
```

I've been googling it but I can't seem to find anything. It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You don't need Javascript for this, CSS is the right tool for the job.

```css
.my-class::before {
  content: attr(title);
}
```

```html
<i class="my-class" title="AB"></i>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `getAttribute`:

```
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.innerText = document.querySelector(".my-class").getAttribute("title");
```

Answer (score 2):

### Without JavaScript

CSS allows you to set the content of pseudo elements (`::before` and `::after`) like this:

```
.my-class::before {
  content: "I am some content!";
}
```

Combine that with the CSS function `attr()` and you will be able to populate the pseudo element's content with an attribute of your element:

```
.my-class::before {
  content: attr(title);
}
```

Keep in mind though, that if you were to add some text to the elements' content like

```
<span class="my-class" title="My Title">Hey, I am some Content!</span>
```

it would render as

> My TitleHey, I am some Content!

### With JavaScript

Use your preferred way of getting access to a DomElement
`document.getElementById`, `document.getElementsByClassName`, `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll` will all do the job.
Then, receive the `title` attribute using `HtmlElement.getAttribute` and insert it as a string into the element's `textContent`:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.my-class');
element.textContent = element.getAttribute('title');
```

Comment: Taking two existing answers, adding some explanatory text and boom, you have an answer that's looking good! Aside from that, `element.title` is more concise and also works.

Comment: fyi: I was composing my answer whilst the others already had written and posted theirs in the meantime @connexo